# GitLab runner fails with unknown failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am currently setting up a Gitlab CICD pipeline to deploy Terraform code with following https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-security/security-operations/infrastructure-security-public/oidc-modules/-/tree/main?ref_type=heads. The pipeline gets stuck in the Getting source from Git repository and crashes. At the top it states that an unknown error occured rerun the pipeline. Even after doing it multiple times the error persists.

Runner version: 16.3
Gitlab EE version: 16.3.2-ee

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.3.0 (8ec04662)
  on runner_cicd XXXXXXX, system ID: s_XXXXXXXXX
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/releases/1.4:v1.0.0 ...
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/releases/1.4:v1.0.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:104f99d4e97abc5ec58424692209eeb491bcbe6254668ec93793e976a333a9d3 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/releases/1.4:v1.0.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/releases/1.4@sha256:10b708737f434674e28cb1f66d997cd8cb431547a8408f347e4ca417693400df ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-XXXXXXX-project-61-concurrent-0 via gitlab-runner-virtual-machine...
Getting source from Git repository
```

```
image:
  name: "$CI_TEMPLATE_REGISTRY_HOST/gitlab-org/terraform-images/releases/1.4:v1.0.0"

stages:
  - validate
  - build

variables:
  WI_POOL_PROVIDER: //iam.googleapis.com/projects/${GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${GOOGLE_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/providers/${GOOGLE_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_PROVIDER_ID}
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT: ${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}  # The relative path to the root directory of the Terraform project
  TF_STATE_NAME: default      # The name of the state file used by the GitLab Managed Terraform state backend
  AUDIENCE: $WI_POOL_PROVIDER
  TOKEN_LIFETIME: 1800
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}

# Set up Application Default Credentials
.google-oidc:auth:
  id_tokens:
    GCP_OIDC_JWT:
      aud: $AUDIENCE
  before_script:
    - curl -s https://gitlab.sov.gcp.t-systems.net/gcp_tsi_sov_gitlab_user/test-cicd-pipeline/-/raw/main/staging-363715-de7b29afd785.json
    - if [ -z "$WI_POOL_PROVIDER" ]; then echo "WI_POOL_PROVIDER is not set."; exit 1; fi;
    - if [ -z "$AUDIENCE" ]; then echo "AUDIENCE is not set."; exit 1; fi;
    - if [ -z "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT" ]; then echo "SERVICE_ACCOUNT is not set."; exit 1; fi;
    - mkdir -p /var/run/secrets/gitlab/
    - echo "$GCP_OIDC_JWT" > /var/run/secrets/gitlab/.gcp-oidc.json
    - unset GCP_OIDC_JWT
    - echo '{"type":"external_account","audience":"%WI_POOL_PROVIDER%","subject_token_type":"urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt","token_url":"https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token","credential_source":{"file":"/var/run/secrets/gitlab/.gcp-oidc.json","format":{"type":"text"}},"service_account_impersonation_url":"https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/%SERVICE_ACCOUNT%:generateAccessToken","service_account_impersonation":{"token_lifetime_seconds":%TOKEN_LIFETIME%}}' \
      | sed -e "s!%WI_POOL_PROVIDER%!$WI_POOL_PROVIDER!" -e "s!%SERVICE_ACCOUNT%!$SERVICE_ACCOUNT!" -e "s!%TOKEN_LIFETIME%!$TOKEN_LIFETIME!" >  /var/run/secrets/gitlab/.gcp-credentials.json
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/run/secrets/gitlab/.gcp-credentials.json
    - |- # Configuration for gcloud, bq and gsutil
      if type gcloud > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        export CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/var/run/secrets/gcloud/
        if [ -n "$GCLOUD_PROJECT" ]; then
          gcloud config set project "$GCLOUD_PROJECT"
        else
          gcloud config set project "$(echo \""$SERVICE_ACCOUNT"\" | sed -e 's/^.*@//g' -e 's/\..*$//g')" # Set a project ID in the service account
         fi
         gcloud auth login --cred-file="${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}"
      fi
  after_script:
    - rm -rf /var/run/secrets/gitlab/ /var/run/secrets/gcloud/


.terraform:fmt:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform fmt
  allow_failure: true

.terraform:validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform validate

.terraform:build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform plan

fmt:
  extends: .terraform:fmt
  needs: []

validate:
  extends: 
    #- .google-oidc:auth
    - .terraform:validate
  needs: []

build:
  extends:
    - .google-oidc:auth
    - .terraform:build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: prepare
```

What could lead to the unknown error? Is it a missconfiguration of the runner or is something wrong in the CI definition?

We already tried different configurations:

- Intentionally missconfigured the service account --> leads to a failure while accessing the GCP API
- Exclude different steps in the CICD configuration --> same error